# How add a mask layer, to mask specific color

Tags: ios, uiview, core-animation, mask

I have a UILabel inside scrollview.

I want to mask part of the scrollview, in a way that when the UILabel goes under that part, it will change it's color.

Couldn't find how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UIView *maskView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 200, 100, 100)];
    maskView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    maskView.alpha = 0.5;
    self.maskView = maskView;
    [self.view addSubview:maskView];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGRect rect = [self.label convertRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100) toView:self.maskView];
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGRect(rect));
    if (rect.origin.y >= self.maskView.frame.size.height || rect.origin.y <= -self.label.frame.size.height) {
        self.label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    } else {
        self.label.backgroundColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    }
}
```

The key is `scrollViewDidScroll:` and `convertRect: toView:`.

[image]

[image]